# Multiple custom post type loops in category.php

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I have multiple custom posts types that use the same category taxonomy. Let's call the CPT's 'venue' and 'story', and say we have categorised each of them as 'foo'.

I already have the following code to ensure they're part of the taxonomy loops:

```
//make sure these custom post types are registered for taxonomy queries

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'query_post_type');
function query_post_type($query) {
  if(is_category() || is_tag()) {
    $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
    if($post_type)
        $post_type = $post_type;
    else
        $post_type = array('nav_menu_item', 'venue', 'story'); // don't forget nav_menu_item to allow menus to work!
    $query->set('post_type',$post_type);
    return $query;
    }
}
```

When I visit example.com/category/foo, category.php is fired up. What I'd like to see is:

> Page starts and shows custom image, title, lead sentence
>
> A title
>   3x items from the 'venue', category foo
>
> A title
>   6x items from the 'story', category foo
>
> Pagination, Footer

Here's category.php: (also at: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b747a2c51bc5bb7a58dd)

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying category pages.
 *
 * Learn more: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package DW Focus
 * @since DW Focus 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>
    <?php
    // vars
    $queried_object = get_queried_object();
    $taxonomy       = $queried_object->taxonomy;
    $image          = get_field('category_image', $queried_object);
    $lead           = get_field('category_lead', $queried_object);
    ?>

<div id="primary" class="site-content category span12">

        <?php

            if( !empty($image) ): ?>
                <div id="featured_image_category" style="height:200px;">
                    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>


        <div class="content-bar row-fluid">
            <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( '%s articles', 'dw-focus' ), '<span>' . single_cat_title( '', false ) . '</span>' ); ?></h1>
        </div>

        <?php if( !empty($lead) ): ?>
            <div class="lead"><p><?php echo $lead; ?></p></div>
        <?php endif; ?>

            <h2 style="text-align: center;">Luxury and Boutique Hotels in <?php printf( __( '%s', 'dw-focus' ), '<span>' . single_cat_title( '', false ) . '</span>' ); ?></h2>

        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'venueloop'); ?>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <h2 style="text-align: center;">Explore <?php printf( __( '%s', 'dw-focus' ), '<span>' . single_cat_title( '', false ) . '</span>' ); ?> with our unique travel experiences</h2>

        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'storyloop' ); ?>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <?php dw_focus_pagenavi(); ?>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Content-part for venueloop and story loop (also at
https://gist.github.com/indietravel/38ed27762fb844eee0a5):

```
<div class="content-inner">
        <?php

            if ( is_category() ) {
                $cat = get_query_var('cat');
                $ourcat = get_category ($cat);
                $category_selected = $ourcat->slug;
            }

            $args = array (
                'post_type'              => 'story',
                'post_status'            => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page'         => '6',
                'category_name'          => $category_selected,
            );

            // The Query
            $cat_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        ?>
        <?php if ( $cat_query -> have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php global $archive_i; $archive_i = 1 ?>
            <?php while ( $cat_query -> have_posts() ) : $cat_query -> the_post(); ?>
                <?php get_template_part('content', 'archive'); ?>
                <?php $archive_i; ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif;

        wp_reset_postdata(); // ADAPTED FOR CUSTOM POST TYPES
        wp_reset_query();

        ?>

    </div>
```

Venue Loop:

```
    <?php

    // WP_Query arguments
    $args = array (
    'post_type'             => 'venue',
    'post_status'           => 'publish',
    'pagination'            => false,
    'posts_per_page'        => '3',
);

// The Query
$venue_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $venue_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $venue_query->have_posts() ) {
        $venue_query->the_post();

        the_title();

    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

For some reason, the outcome is that the page always shows,

> Page starts and shows custom image, title, lead sentence
>
> A title
>   3x items from the 'venue' & 'story' CPT, category foo
>
> A title
>   3x items from the 'venue' & 'story' CPT, category foo
>
> Pagination, Footer

Comment: Please don't use external services to host your code. Add all relevant code directly to your post in the form of an [edit]

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```
//make sure these custom post types are registered for taxonomy queries

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'query_post_type');
function query_post_type($query) {
  if(is_category() || is_tag()) {
    $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
    if($post_type)
        $post_type = $post_type;
    else
        $post_type = array('nav_menu_item', 'venue', 'story'); // don't forget nav_menu_item to allow menus to work!
    $query->set('post_type',$post_type);
    return $query;
    }
}
```

was filtering the results (before? after?) the in-template query. As such, it was completely obliterating the requests to only use the requested post type. Changed to

```
//make sure these custom post types are registered for taxonomy queries

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'query_post_type');
function query_post_type($query) {
  if( is_tag() ) {
    $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
    if($post_type)
        $post_type = $post_type;
    else
        $post_type = array('nav_menu_item', 'venue', 'story'); // don't forget nav_menu_item to allow menus to work!
    $query->set('post_type',$post_type);
    return $query;
    }
}
```

And then on-page custom queries started working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    <?php 
    $args = array ( 'post_type' => array( 'nav_menu_item', 'venue', 'story' )   );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

    the_title();
    the_content();

    endwhile; 
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
    ?>
```

Comment: any one know how to show categories in this loop related to each posts.